# Wordpress plugin ajax request works fine locally but production

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I developing a WP plugin, the form submitted via ajax/post is working fine locally without any error, but drops a 400 Bad Request when I upload it to production.
No error messages just retuns a 0 (zero).

My jquery as simple as:

```
var url  = windows.globalObject.ajaxUrl,
    data = form.serialize();

$.post(url, data, function (obj) {
   if (obj.success === 1) {
      content.html(obj.html);
   } else {
      console.log(obj.message);
   }
}, 'json');
```

And this is how I register the script in my module:

```
add_action('wp_footer', function () {
   $includes_path = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '../components/includes/';

   wp_register_script('scripts', $includes_path . "scripts.js", array('jquery'), null, true);
   wp_enqueue_script('scripts');

   wp_localize_script( 'scripts', 'globalObject', ['ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=handle_submit', 'http')]);
});

add_action( 'wp_ajax_handle_submit', [$this, 'handle_submit']);
```

Any idea or experience on this issue?

Comment: Can you please check the permission for wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. Please make sure you have provided 774 permission to the file.

Comment: Thx @PreP, I have checked. It was only 644, I changed to 774, but it returns 404, so it looks 755 is the highest proper value. And I also changed the permission of all PHP files in wp-admin to 755, but the error is still 400.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, and I would like to save debugging hours to anybody who has a 400 Bad Request error with a returned zero.

The magic is in the end part of admin-ajax.php. There is a condition which checks if a user has logged or not. And regarding to this, it simply call the given action. The  possible action name prefix variations are:

**wp_ajax_nopriv_**[yourActionName] if you would like to achievable your action to anybody, even if they not logged, or

**wp_ajax_**[yourActionName] if you want to restrict your action only to logged users and prevent access to everyone who has not logged.

admin-ajax.php uses $_REQUEST, so you could place your action name both into the URL or as a part of your form in a hidden field. In this case, your action name will not appear in the called ajax URL.